# RXjava code conversion from 1.0 to 2.0 - subscriber.isUnsubscribed() not available

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I am following book which uses `subscriber.isUnsubscribed()` but it is no longer available in version 2.0. Can somebody guide me how to rewrite this code to be able to use `isUnsubscribed` check in the Observable lambda?

```
Observable<BigInteger> naturalNumbers = Observable.create(
    subscriber -> {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            BigInteger i = ZERO;
            while (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onNext(i);
                i = i.add(ONE);
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();
    });


Subscription subscription = naturalNumbers.subscribe(x -> log(x));
//after some time...
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do there?

Comment: This is an example from the 'Infinite streams' chapter from Tomasz Nurkiewicz book on rxjava. I have updated code to the exact one from the book.

Comment: I am thinking that Flowable is the correct use here, but does that mean that Observable from 2.0 no longer supports checking whether there is a subscription to it?

Comment: Isn't it `isDisposed`?